# Why can't I see the image on my Telerik button

Tags: c#, image, xaml, telerik

This is a part of a `xaml` file in my C# program:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="General/Tests">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <telerik:RadRibbonButton Command="{Binding Path=...}" Style="{StaticResource RibbonTabButton}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="/ThisProject;component/Pictures/Coldstart.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Coldstart all zones" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadRibbonButton>
    </StackPanel>
</telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
```

I have added the "<Image Source ..." piece of source code by dragging that filename from the Solution explorer into the `xaml` file, yet I don't see anything when I run the code. The XAML designer is not working properly, so I need to run the project in order to see if it works.

That mentioned `*.png` file is something I have added to my project, it looks as follows in the `*.csproj` file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" 
         DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="ThisProject.ico" />
    <Content Include="Pictures\Coldstart.png" />
    ...
  ...
```

Why don't I see the picture, but only the text of the "Coldstart" button? Do I need to do any action (like an "image import") to make this work?

For your information, this is what is looks like (don't worry about not seeing the header of the `RadRibbonGroup`, it is visible more to the right but the entire thing is too large):

[image]

I have modified the `<Content>` into a `<Resource>` tag:

```
<Resource Include="Pictures\Coldstart.png" >
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Resource>
```

This is A LOT better, but the image is too large. Is there an "AutoResize" option to the image or to the `RadRibbonButton`?

It currently looks as follows (incomplete image and no room for the text anymore):

[image]

Comment: instead of Content use Resource - consider declaring all files as resource in your pictures directory with this `<Resource Include="Pictures\**\*.*" />` (notice: this also includes all sub directories)

Comment: @RandRandom: WAW! I've been searching for this for an entire day and you solve that in minutes. Do you know if an auto-resize is possible, as described in the edit of my question? You can write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: wpf image control does have a stretch option - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.stretch - though you would need to replace your stackpanel with a grid - a stackpanel tells all children to be as big as the possible want, a grid will limit the dimension - so, I would do a grid with two rows

Comment: @RandRandom: don't worry. I've added the `Width="32"` to my `Image` properties and now it works. Please mention your first comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Content`

```
<Content Include="Pictures\Coldstart.png" />
```

use `Resource`

```
<Resource Include="Pictures\Coldstart.png" />
```

consider declaring all files as resource in your pictures directory with this

```
<Resource Include="Pictures\**\*.*" />
```

(notice: this also includes all sub directories)